# Group search results by album in Flickr

Tags: ios, flickr

My photos file names have the date in them e.g. 2015-05-15-123.jpg so when I do a Search in the iOS app for say 2015 I get all photos taken in 2015 but they are shown in a flat list. Is there a way to group them by Album instead?

Comment: Is this question specifically about using the iOS app?

Comment: Yes, it is about using the iOS app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked with version 4.0.1 of the iOS flickr app. I am sorry to say, but it is **not possible** to group yearly search results by album with this version. Here is a screenshot of my search results:

[image: ios flickr app screenshot]

By the way, the file names of the uploaded are irrelevant for flickr, as they take the date info from metadata within the photo, via [EXIF data](http://www.digital-photo-secrets.com/tip/38/what-is-exif/).

Comment: Thanks. That's a bummer. My folders are organized using Year/Event/bunch of files in folder(s). The Windows Uploadr auto creates a album for each leaf node/folder. Basically, I was hoping to get the best of both worlds i.e  navigate Flickr like a traditional folder hierarchy or using the metadata. Looks like my only option is to browse the timeline view, identify the date I need and then pick any photo, click the Info icon, see what Album it is filed under and go to that Album. Kinda cumbersome.